# eureka server and gateway is on one server and eureka client is on another server

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, microservices

I have two servers. On the 1st server, I have a eureka server, gateway and exam-mgmnt service(Eureka client).
we can call exam-mgmnt rest API through a gateway. 
and on the 2nd server, I hosted school-mgmnt service,
but I am unable to call school-mgmnt service rest API through a gateway.

## MY ALL CONFIGURATION IS HERE :

```
exam-mgmnt    application.properties contain:
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://XX:XX:XX:XX:8088/eureka
          eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

=====================================================

```
exam-mgmnt    bootstrap.yml contain : 
             spring:
                  application:
                       name: exam-mgmnt
```

=====================================================

```
exam-mgmnt     Dockerfile contain
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8083:8080
ADD /build/libs/exam-mgmnt.jar exam-mgmnt.jar
```

## ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","exam-mgmnt.jar"]

```
school-mgmnt   application.properties
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://XX:XX:XX:XX:8088/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

========================================================

```
school-mgmnt  bootstrap.yml contain :
           spring:
                  application:
                       name: school-mgmnt
```

=======================================================

```
school-mgmnt   Dockerfile conatin
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8081:8080
ADD /build/libs/school-mgmnt.jar school-mgmnt.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","school-mgmnt.jar"]
```

======================================================

Comment: 1. does the school-mgmnt server successful register itself in eureka 2. can 35.154.235.28 access the 8081 port of the 2nd server

Comment: 1.yes,school-mgmnt server successful register itself in eureka 2.yes 2nd server's 8081 port is open.

Comment: does the school-mgmnt server register its docker ip in the eureka? maybe this is the problem since gateway cannot access another ecs's docker inner network